# PHP script inside jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

That's what I have:

```
<a href="<?=$arItem["LINK"]?>#nav-link">LinkName</a>
```

Here `<?=$arItem["LINK"]?>` I'm getting some link, and I want to add to the end of this link some extra hashtag parameter `#nav-link`.

But the main problem is that PHP is executing on the server side, so, when I click the link, I get only link from the `<?=$arItem["LINK"]?>` (somesite.com). After second click, I have necessary code `somesite.com/#nav-link`.

So, is it possible to get `somesite.com/#nav-link` after first click?

Comment: `But the main problem is that PHP is executing on the server side` you've answerd your question.. You will need to get the PHP to return the formatted JS as a html string and use that..

Comment: there is too much of your code missing.

Comment: Nope, as you said the request is treated on the server side. You have to return the link with #nav-link tag directly from the server

Comment: Can't you just append #nav-link to the href? `$("#id").attr("href", $("#id).attr("href") + "#nav-link");` on load.

Comment: @Jite In this case result is the same